# Apple A4 processor. What is it?

Tags: cpu

What do you think about internals of Apple A4 processor for iPad?

Is it ARM7 or ARM9 core from P.A.Semi or ARM Cortex-A9 MPCore based SoC?

Comment: How many cores does it have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based upon all the articles posted:

[A4 unveiled](http://www.brightsideofnews.com/news/2010/1/27/apple-a4-soc-unveiled---its-an-arm-cpu-and-the-gpu!.aspx)

> A4 is a System-on-a-Chip, or SOC, that integrates the main processor [ARM Cortex-A9, identical to ones used in nVidia Tegra and Qualcomm Snapdragon] with graphics silicon [ARM Mali GPU], and other functions like the memory controller on one piece of silicon - not unlike what Intel is trying to achieve with its future "Moorestown" Atom processor that debuted inside LG's Smartphone.

[C|net Asia](http://asia.cnet.com/crave/2010/01/29/apple-a4-chip-really-means-4th-generation-arm-processor-/)

> According to reports, neither the Cupertino company nor PA Semi (which was purchased by the former) had anything to do with the A4 processor. Turns out that Apple's newest baby is an ARM Cortex-A9 processor with an ARM Mali GPU, which is similar to the ones used by the Nvidia Tegra and Qualcomm Snapdragon platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Apple's previous partnerships, I believe it will be some sort of ARM based CPU.

Details are sketchy at best, and there is no official release, but at the moment all rumours are pointing towards it being based on the same platform as Nvidia's Tegra 2 - a `Cortex-A9 MPCore`.

However, everything can change before release.